# Is a sorcerer with the domain-access alternative class feature considered both an arcane and a divine caster?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spellcasting, divine

The alternative class feature Domain Access (*Complete Champion*, p. 52) reads, in part:

> Choose one cleric domain. If you worship a specific deity, the domain you choose must be one to
> which your deity grants access. You gain the granted power of the chosen domain. In addition, **you can cast one domain spell of each spell level** available to you per day from that domain.

Does having access to the domain spells make a sorcer qualify for any prestige class that requires the PC to be a divine caster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your DM. There is no actual definition of “divine spellcaster,” and there is no way to know if this or other corner-cases (e.g. Alternate Source Spell, Southern Magician) actually count or not.

This kind of question has come up quite a few times—though the specifics are different enough each time that it’s hard to assign any as a duplicate of the other, the answers wind up the same. See also:

- [Progress a theurge with another theurge?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/67987/4563)
- [Progress a rainbow servant twice per level with mystic theurge?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/39576/4563)
- [Ability to cast arcane spells vs. arcane spellcasting class](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/24582/4563)
- [Divine Metamagic on arcane spells via Alternate Source Spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/150176/4563)
- [Advancing cleric/wizard with ultimate magus, again with Alternate Source Spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/91545/4563)
- [Wizard-only ultimate magus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/90520/4563)
- [What is a “psionic class” for erudites?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/162633/4563) (Psionics actually *does* define a few classes as explicitly “psionic classes”—but then fails to keep that list updated or handle corner cases.)